# Updating Class on Scroll Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a page with a fixed menu on the right side which is generated whenever a header with the `link-list-item` class is present. I want to update the menu with an active class whenever these items are passed on the scroll.  The issue I'm running into is that it's only updated whenever the scroll reaches the title, after which it is removed. I want the menu item to keep the active class until it reaches the next title, or if there's no header above the scroll point. Wrapping each section in a div is not an option with the way the page is made up.

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <header class="header-tab-label row">
    <h5 id="alaska" class="link-list-label">Alaska</h5>
  </header>
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <header class="header-tab-label row">
    <h5 id="austin" class="link-list-label">Austin</h5>
  </header>
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <header class="header-tab-label row">
    <h5 id="england" class="link-list-label">England</h5>
  </header>
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
  <p>Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</p> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
(function($) {

  $linklistLabel = $(".link-list-label");
  $linkList = $(".link-list");
  $linkListItem = $linkList.find("li");

  $linklistLabel.each(function(index) {
    $linkList.append('<a href="#' + $(this).text().toLowerCase() + '"><li>' + $(this).text() + '</li></a>');
  });

  function onScroll(event) {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $linkList.find('a').each(function() {
      var currLink = $(this);
      console.log(currLink);
      var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
      if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $linkListItem.removeClass("active");
        currLink.addClass("active");
      } else {
        currLink.removeClass("active");
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(document).off("scroll");

      $('a').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      })
      $(this).addClass('active');

      var target = this.hash,
        menu = target;
      $target = $(target);
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + 2
      }, 500, 'swing', function() {
        window.location.hash = target;
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
      });
    });
  });

})(jQuery);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kx8Ljm9t/1/

Comment: There is tons of `jQuery` plugin that do it for you, there is no problem if you using other people's code.

Comment: That doesn't really help. Can you at least link to one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very quickly coded - this would need more testing:

```
$linkListA = $(".link-list a");
function onScroll(event) {
      var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
      for (var i = 0; i < $linklistLabel.length; i++) {
         if ($linklistLabel.eq(i).offset().top - scrollPos < 100 &&
          $linklistLabel.eq(i).offset().top - scrollPos > -100) {
                 $linkListA.removeClass('active');
                 var id = $linklistLabel.eq(i).prop('id');
                 $('a[href="#'+id+'"]').addClass('active');
         } else if ($linklistLabel.eq(0).offset().top - scrollPos  >= 100) {
                 $linkListA.removeClass('active');
         }
      }
};
```

I prefer it the other way around, meaning at every scroll I loop over all headers (and not over the links). So at every scroll movement you look if there is a header within 100px to the top and to the bottom - if yes remove the active class from all links and add the class for the current header.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n0scg0m5/

Comment: This works. Although the active class does not get removed if there's no header above the scroll.

Comment: that's true. It's getting more and more complicated the more "special cases" you have. For the case of a large text before the first header occurs you can add the "else if" part I updated in my answer